# how do i run my calculation app using variables instead of state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I had a functioning eBay fee calculator app and I was using `state` to collect and calculate the values from the text input fields.

I ran into some errors because I was using `setState` in the `render()` method.. I posted a separate question on StackOverflow and was advised to move `state` into variables using `let` and `const`, and not to use `state`.

However, now I'm left with a bunch of code that I'm not sure what to change/keep in order to get my app working again.

It would be a huge help if an experienced dev could help me with this.

```
 render() {
    let soldPrice = 0;
    let shippingCost = 0;
    let shippingCharge = 0;
    let itemCost = 0;
    let profit = " ";
    const paypalFee = 0.3;
    const paypalFeePercentage = 0.029;
    const ebayFee = 0.1;

    soldPrice += shippingCharge;

    const calculation =
      soldPrice -
      soldPrice * paypalFeePercentage -
      paypalFee -
      soldPrice * ebayFee -
      shippingCost -
      itemCost;

    const roundedNumber = calculation.toPrecision(i);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NumberInput value={shippingCharge} />
        <NumberInput
          onchange={shippingCost => this.setState({ shippingCost })}
        />
        {/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */}
        {/* I use this to change the value of item cost state when the user filled out the input for 
        how much the item costs them to buy but im not sure how to update the variables onChange  */}
        {/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */}
        <NumberInput onchange={itemCost => this.setState({ itemCost })} />
        <NumberInput onchange={itemCost => this.setState({ itemCost })} />
        <NumberInput onchange={itemCost => this.setState({ itemCost })} />
        <Text>TOTAL PROFIT:{roundedNumber}</Text>
        {/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */}
        {/* I am also trying to figure out how to calculate the profit, when the user clicks the calculate button */}
        {/* ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// */}
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.calculateProfit}>
          <Text>Calculate </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

- **My `NumberInput` Component:**

```
    export default class NumberInput extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <TextInput
            keyboardType={"numeric"}
            onChangeText={this.props.onchange}
            value={this.props.value}
          />
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's the *problem* with the code you've posted? Give a [mcve].

Comment: That I don't know how to call a calculate function

Comment: Can you post more of your code or use CodeSandbox.io to create a minimal example? It's hard to help when not all of the code is supplied.

Comment: Ok will do in about an hour

Comment: @MattOestreich don't encourage people to just post more code or offsite links; we want minimal examples *in the question*, per the link in my comment above.

Comment: @jonrsharpe posting complete code would give us a minimal reproducible example.... even your link says to post complete code... furthermore, if a CodeSandbox gives us a working minimal reproducible example, isn't that what we're asking for???  If OP were to post more complete code blocks *in the question* or if they posted a link/StackSnippet containing a working reproducible example *in the question* (not sure where else they would post either of those things??) - then you're getting what you asked for.  You have no valid point, and your statement is redundant.

Comment: @MattOestreich **minimal** complete, not just "more" or "all of the code". And codesandbox is off site, *not* in the question.

Comment: @MattOestreich how is the difference between on this site and elsewhere "splitting hairs"? I'd already posted a link you the actual guidance, nobody asked you to blunder in here with contradictory advice.

Comment: I got rid of all the extra code i only left in code that is relevant to calculating the total profit

Comment: i also tried implementing some if the minimal reproducible example principles

Comment: @prog Do you have the link to the other StackOverflow question? I don't see how you could do this without using `state`, since the values are dynamic. The only thing I can think of is they were against using `setState` inline on the elements (inside `render`), and wanted you to create methods to handle `state` changes. This would make changes easier to see.. While this example is not using your formula, it still uses a formula - hope this helps: https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/VwZebMa?editors=1010